# Azure Cosmos DB - Private Endpoint and Failover?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-private-link

I have provisioned Cosmos DB with the following configurations

1. West US - Primary => Read & Write
2. East US - Secondary => Read

[image]

and have configured the private endpoints as shown below

[image]

West US Configuration
[image]

East US Configuration
[image]

Private DNS Configuration
[image]

I do understand that Azure will take care of the DNS update to make sure that FQDN points to the right cosmos DB instance in case of a failover.

As I am using Private Endpoints, Am I expected to make any changes/updates on the Private Endpoints in case of a failover?

Answer (score 0):

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_WrJT7pLRv4) helped solve a similar scenario. My setup:

- 2 Resource Groups: Resource Group A & Resource Group B
- 2 VNETs in different locations: Location A & Location B
- 2x CosmosDB Private DNS Zones in each Resource Group
- 2 Private Endpoints for CosmosDB
- Setup DNS Config for 1 Private Endpoint in CosmosDB Private DNS Zone in Location A
- Setup DNS Config for other Private Endpoint in CosmosDB Private DNS Zone in Location B

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35207116)